# If use a regex expression to match a string. Can I substitute another line?

Tags: perl

If I use a regex expression to match a string, can I change a string in a different line? Basically, if `foo` exists, I want to change `bar` to `soap`. `bar` appears on a different line in a text file. `foo`, if present, will always appear before `bar`.

```
while (<FILE>) {
   if (m/foo/){
       s/bar/soap/;
   }
}
```

Data file:

```
foo
food
red
bar
blue
```

Comment: If `foo` exists anywhere in the entire file? Or does `foo` have to come before `bar`?

Comment: in this case it should be before.

Comment: without change the code structure a lot, you could use the flip-flop operator. I'm not sure about the readability though : `s/bar/soap/ if /foo/ .. 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your `if` statement matches, the value of `$_` has not yet changed.  The line that `m//` has matched against is the same line that you are attempting to have `s///` search-and-replace.  Instead you need to set a flag that you can later check, once the new line has been hit:

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Cannot open $filename: $!\n";
my $flag = 0;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
   $flag = 1 if $line =~ /foo/;
   $line =~ s/bar/soap/ if $flag;
}
```

Comment: If I were to add a capture group within this line

    $flag = 1 if $line =~ /(fo)o/;

would I be able to store that capture group into a variable?

EDIT: NVM I found out if I just add AND $variable = $1 at the end of that line it works just fine.

Comment: @Gary like `($group, $flag) = ($1, 1) if $line =~ /(fo)o/` for instance.

Comment: @Gary note that adding `and $variable = $1` at the end will not work if `$1` is a falsy value (`0` for instance).

Comment: @Dada thank you I will make note of that for the future!